How to interpret entirely neutral response
Very infrequently, I sometimes post a question that gets 0 upvotes, downvotes, or interaction at all, i.e. comments.
By very infrequently, I mean exactly twice; but the first time I did eventually figure out the root cause, which was that it was my first post ever to the site and I did word vomit that was both technically fine but also not easy to respond to, so I cleaned it up, and netted 1 upvote.
This most recent time, I am not sure what I have done... incorrectly? This time, I have not even received a stray comment or edit like I have previously that tipped me off to my error. It also can't be because I word vomited like before, because I made sure to make the purpose of my question clear. So I'm not sure if I even made any mistake or not.
I say this all to say, what are the most likely reasons that a question will get no interaction, as opposed to positive or negative interaction?

Do you really want an answer to the general question of reasons why a hypothetical question will get no interaction? or do you want to know why your specific question is getting no interaction? If the latter, it would help to link to the question so we can give some informed opinions.

If it's the question beginning, "Let $L$ be a model of an ortholattice," I'd say that that sentence is enough to convince 99% of the users of this site that they will not have anything useful to contribute to the discussion.

@GerryMyerson general list of reasons is preferable, which is why I omitted the link.

I figure that if it were to happen again, then having a more general list would be better, and also there's not much I can do about my latest question, probably.

Assuming, along with @GerryMyerson, that this is the question you are referring to...for me, at least, the issue is that I have no idea what an ortholattice is.  Simple as that.  Might be a perfectly good question, might not.  I have no way of knowing and no way of offering any useful advice.  Perhaps it's a widely understood term, even if I don't happen to know it.  On the chance that it isn't a widely understood term, I would suggest including the definition, or at least linking to the definition.

@lulu sure, I can provide a link I guess. Maybe there is still hope for my question being looked at.

Well, I just broke the no-engagement curse on my latest question with the help of Gerry Myerson and lulu, so I figure I will synthesize a primary cause:
Generally, it seems 0-upvotes-0-downvotes-0-comments occurs when a question either

has too many details
has details missing

that make it hard to engage with, but well-written enough to not get negative feedback either. So generally the best way to get feedback is to edit the question to be more approachable to a random user.
